# For a complex number $z$ applies to $\operatorname{Re} (z) = 5$.

Tags: trigonometry

For a complex number $z$ applies to $\operatorname{Re} (z) = 5$. What values can $\operatorname{Re} (1/z)$ assume to be?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there is a typo in your question, if you mean $\operatorname{Re}(\frac{1}{z})$, then write
$$z=x+iy$$
$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{x+iy}=\frac{x-iy}{(x+iy)(x-iy)}=\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}-i\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$$
thus
$$\operatorname{Re}\Big(\frac{1}{z}\Big)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$$
In your case, you have $x=5$, hence

$$\operatorname{Re}\Big(\frac{1}{z}\Big)=\frac{5}{25+y^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Real part of a real is nothing but itself so $1/2$.

Comment: I don't understand how is this an answer to op's question

Comment: OH! Initially it was Re(1/2) instead of Re(1/z)